# Transformations of different models not working

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glsl, transformation

I'm using OpenGL with shaders; glm for the maths.

In my code, I have two models: modelA and modelB. I have a Transformable class that translates, scales, rotates on different axes, and these are multiplied with a transformation matrix which I will use to define the transformation of any 'thing'. What's important is that this Transformable class returns the transformation matrix, and that will be multiplied by a model matrix to apply a certain transformation. modelA and modelB are both of type Model. This class inherits from Transformable because it is transformable. So, it has a function that returns the transformation matrix. The problem is where it all comes together:

```
class scene
{
public:
    scene();
    bool initialize();
    void render();

private:
    Model modelA, modelB;
    glm::mat4 modelMatrix;

    void passUniforms();
};
```

Then in the initialize function:

```
initialize()
{
    modelA.load("file.obj");
    modelB.load("file2.3ds");
    // compile and link shaders
    // init lighting
    // init camera

    modelA.translate(glm::vec3(0.f, 10.f, 0.f));
    modelB.translate(glm::vec3(-10.f, 0.f, 0.f));

    modelMatrix *= modelA.getTransformationMatrix();
}

passUniforms()
{
    auto MVP = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

    GLint MVP_id = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "MVP");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MVP_id, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));

    // pass other uniforms
}

void render()
{
    passUniforms();
    modelA.render(programHandle);
    modelB.render(programHandle);
}
```

Now, let's make this clear: both models render just fine, and **I am NOT making a scene graph**. The lighting works, the camera can view the models, and the models are textured all fine. But there's one problem: **the transformations are all the same!**

At first glance I can see where the problem is: I'm not taking into account the transformation of modelB, so it's no wonder OpenGL is transforming everything according to the transformation matrix of modelA. Call me stupid, or maybe I'm just not doing something right here; but I am now stuck in how I can update each model's positions independently from one another. My first solution was to do this:

```
initialize()
{
    // load models, compile shaders etc

    modelA.translate(glm::vec3(0.f, 10.f, 0.f));
    modelB.translate(glm::vec3(-10.f, 0.f, 0.f));

    modelMatrix *= modelA.getTransMatrix();
    passUniforms();

    modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);

    modelMatrix *= modelB.getTransMatrix();
    passUniforms();
}
```

That didn't work either; both models still bear the same transformations as one another. So, I thought maybe it had something to do with my vertex shader since that's where I'm applying the transformations:

```
#version 430

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vp; // vertex position
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vt; // vertex textures
layout (location = 2) in vec3 vn; // vertex normals

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projMatrix;
uniform mat4 MVP;

// other things

void main()
{
    // eye calculations

    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vp, 1.0);
}
```

At the time of writing, I'm thinking of various solutions I could effect in resolving this issue. Though, I think an objective analysis of my own code would be better so I can see where I'm wrong here. How could I have each model be rendered with an independent transformation from one another? I don't want the transformation of modelA to also be the transformation of modelB. If the information here isn't enough, ask for which others you require. I hope you can understand my predicament here. :-)

Comment: Where do you compute MVP matrix? Is it always sync with model matrix when you're rendering a single mesh?

Comment: I compute MVP matrix in the passUniforms() function with the scene class. I'm not sure what you mean by the second statement. What do you mean if it's always in sync with the model matrix?

Comment: You have to update your uniforms between each model rendering, If you update those once at the begining, the same matrices will be use for for render...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you're not making an explicit scene graph there's always some kind of simple scene graph involved if you have more than one object to render.

You have to reset to the identity matrix and do the matrix multiplications separately for each object.

```
initialize()
{
    modelA.load("file.obj");
    modelB.load("file2.3ds");
    // compile and link shaders
    // init lighting
    // init camera


    modelB.translate(glm::vec3(-10.f, 0.f, 0.f));
}

passUniforms()
{
    auto MVP = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix;

    GLint MVP_id = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "MVP");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MVP_id, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));

    // pass other uniforms
}

void render()
{
    modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    modelMatrix *= modelA.getTransformationMatrix();
    passUniforms();
    modelA.render(programHandle);

    modelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
    modelMatrix *= modelB.getTransformationMatrix();
    passUniforms();
    modelB.render(programHandle);
}
```

There's no need to calculate inverses.

Comment: OMG, thank you very much!! My issue has been resolved. Thank you, and raveesh too!

Comment: @rpress The inverse matrix calculation depends entirely on context like I specified. The calculation of inverses would still make sense if a part of the translation that is common to both model A and B is placed in model matrix, something like this is often done when you have multiple models - The first model's position is chosen as the "origin" and saved in a matrix (model matrix here for instance) and the remaining translations are given with respect to these. But since here the model positions seem to be small numbers it might not be necessary.

Comment: @raveesh You're absolutely right. My first sentence was about implicit scene graphs. The rest was specific to this particular problem. If you use a matrix stack you don't need inverses for forward scene graph traversal. If you need to do a pick test to find out which object is at a specific point then you need inverses, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not clear as to in which functions you were implementing your first solution that you suggested, i think something like this will work -

```
initialize()
{
    modelA.load("file.obj");
    modelB.load("file2.3ds");
    // compile and link shaders
    // init lighting
    // init camera

    modelA.translate(glm::vec3(0.f, 10.f, 0.f));
    modelB.translate(glm::vec3(-10.f, 0.f, 0.f));
}
void render()
{
   modelMatrix *= modelA.getTransMatrix();
   passUniforms();
   modelA.render(programHandle);

   // use the appropriate func to find inverse here to get original modelMatrix
   // if it not identity
   modelMatrix *= modelA.getTransMatrix().inverse;
   modelMatrix *= modelB.getTransMatrix();
   passUniforms();
   modelB.render(programHandle);
}
```